# make before each cest file in codeception

Tags: testing, hook, codeception

I want to prepare data and fixtures before different entire CEST file and only one-time the same thing for the after

But I'm using the _before and _after function in CEST it runs before and after each function in my CEST

could someone help me please

Comment: Do you work with /tests/acceptance/_bootstrap.php ?

Comment: I don't really get what you are talking about but I've runned the command codeception bootstrap